# Non-uniform FFT forward and backward test in 1D

Tags: c++, fft

I am learning to use a c++ library to perform non-uniform FFT ([NUFFT](https://finufft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/math.html)). The library provides 3 types of NUFFT.

- Type 1: forward transform from a non-uniform x grid to a uniform k-space grid.
- Type 2: backward transform from a uniform k-space grid to a non-uniform x grid
- Type 3: from non-uniform to non-uniform

I tested the library in 1D by performing NUFFT on a test function sin(x) from -pi to pi using Type1 NUFFT, transform it back using Type2 NUFFT, and compare the output with sin(x). At first, I tested it on a uniform x grid, which shows a very small error. The error unfortunately is very large when the test is done on a non-uniform x grid.

Two possibilities:

- My implementation of NUFFT is incorrect, but the implementation is rather simple, so I doubt if this is the case.
- The author mentions that Type2 is NOT the inverse of Type1, so I believe that might be the problem. Since I am not an expert in NUFFT, I wonder if there is an alternative way to perform a forward/backward test with NUFFT?
- My purpose is to develop a FFT Poisson solver on a irregular mesh, so I need to perform NUFFT forward and backward, and therefore important to overcome this problem. Besides using FINUFFT, any other suggestion is also welcome.

Thank you for reading.
The code is here for those who is interested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <functional>
#include "finufft/src/finufft.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double pi = 3.14159265359;
    int N = 128*2;
    int i;
    double X[N]; 
    double L  = 2*pi;
    double dx = L/(N);
    nufft_opts opts; finufft_default_opts(&opts);
    complex<double> R = complex<double>(1.0,0.0);  // the real unit
    complex<double> in1[N], out1[N], out2[N];    

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          //X[i] = -(L/2) + i*dx ; // uniform grid
          X[i] = -(L/2) + pow(double(i)/N,7.0)*L; //non-uniform grid
          in1[i] = sin(X[i])*R ;}

    int ier = finufft1d1(N,X,in1,-1,1e-10,N,out1,opts); // type-1 NUFFT
    int ier2 = finufft1d2(N,X,out2,+1,1e-10,N,out1,opts); // type-2 NUFFT

    // checking the error
    double erl1 = 0.;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            erl1 += fabs( in1[i].real() -  out2[i].real()/(N))*dx; 
    }
    std::cout<< erl1 <<" " << ier << " "<< ier2<< std::endl ;  // error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally you should never use `malloc` in C++ programs. If you need an array whose size is known at compile-time (like your code does) then use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), or if the size isn't known at compile-time (or you don't want the array on the stack) use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). If for some reason you think you need to handle memory yourself (please don't) then use `new[]` to allocate *and construct* the data.

Comment: Did you try some tests with a lower `sin` frequency ? It may happen that you get some kinds of aliasing with such a high sinus frequency at the input. You may try something like `sin(X[i]/10)`.

Comment: Non-uniform Fourier Transform? The only way to inverse it - is to write down the matrix of linear equations and invert it. O(n^3) operations. I suggest you drop the idea and find alternative solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Im still new to c++ coding, so thanks for telling me about that. I have changed the declaration of the array based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the developer made an update on their page which answers exactly my question. https://finufft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#periodic-poisson-solve-on-non-cartesian-quadrature-grid. In brief, their NUFFT code is **NOT** good in the case of fully adaptive scheme, but I would still provide an answer and code here for completeness.

There are two ingredients missing in my code.

(1) I need to multiply the function, sin(x), with a weight before using NUFFT. The weight comes from the determinant of the Jacobian in their 2D example, so the weight is simply the derivative the of the nonuniform coordinate with respect to the uniform coordinate dx/dksi for a 1D example.

(2) Nk must be smaller than N.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <functional>
#include "finufft/src/finufft.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double pi = 3.14159265359;
    int N = 128*2;
    int Nk = 32; // smaller than N
    int i;
    double X[N]; 
    double L  = 2*pi;
    double dx = L/(N);
    nufft_opts opts; finufft_default_opts(&opts);
    complex<double> R = complex<double>(1.0,0.0);  // the real unit
    complex<double> in1[N], out1[N], out2[N];    

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      ksi[i] = -(L/2) + i*dx ; //uniform grid
      X[i] = -(L/2) + pow(double(i)/(N-1),6)*L; //nonuniform grid
    }
    dX = der(ksi,X,1);  // your own derivative code
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      in1[i] = sin(X[i]) * dX[i] * R ; // applying weight
    }     

    int ier = finufft1d1(N,X,in1,-1,1e-10,Nk,out1,opts); // type-1 NUFFT
    int ier2 = finufft1d2(N,X,out2,+1,1e-10,Nk,out1,opts); // type-2 NUFFT

    // checking the error
    double erl1 = 0.;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            erl1 += fabs( in1[i].real() -  out2[i].real()/(N))*dx; 
    }
    std::cout<< erl1 <<" " << ier << " "<< ier2<< std::endl ;  // error

    return 0;
}
```